# check if this element OR this element is hovered with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, conditional-statements, mouseover

I have two separate elements in my DOM that require a change when either one is hovered. When the link is hovered, the image src needs to change (easy) AND the link color needs to change. When the image is hovered, the same effect needs to happen (image src changes & link color changes)

This is actually quite easy to do, but I have a feeling there is a MUCH easier way to do it then the approach I am taking. Currently I am going through each of the 8 elements and testing if they are hovered individually. This works good, but there is so much more jQuery here than I feel there should be.

I tried adding the attribute `onmouseover` to both of the elements and triggering the same function, but for some reason the function wasn't triggering.

Is there a way to test if either element is hovered and trigger a function if either one is? Something like this:

```
if($(#elm1).hover() || $('#elm2').hover()) {
    //effect here
}
```

OR

```
if($('#elm1').is(':hover') || $('#elm2').is(':hover')) {
    //effect here
}
```

I tried my example code above, but wasn't getting any results. Is there a way to do this or am I stuck with checking each individual element?

Comment: var isHovered = $('#elem').is(":hover"); to return boolean

Comment: why dont you add a class like `hovered` when you do hover() and check `.hovered` :)

Comment: Because I guess jQuery already stores that state, making it double won't do anything good

Comment: the `var isHovered` thing won't work because I still have to check 8 different elements individually with that. I'm trying to check the link and the image in the same function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works, you're just running it on page load, not when the mouse moves

```
$(document).mousemove(function() {    
    if($('#elm1').is(':hover') || $('#elm2').is(':hover')) {
        // Do stuff
    }
    else {
        // Revert do stuff or do other stuff
    }
});
```

[**Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/LKLL5/)

But, as other's have said, jQuery already knows the `hover` state, so doing it this way would be unnecessary. In practice you should use the same selector to apply the function to it

```
$('#idOne, #idTwo').hover(function() { /* Do stuff */ });
```

Comment: Oh duh. This works just how I needed. I don't know why I didn't think of this myself. Thanks! Will accept answer when I can

Comment: It will select elements on every mousemove event, not quite efficent, you should select them first and use variables.

You could as well listen to mouseenter and mouseleave on that element.

Comment: @neatcoding Agreed! This is quite an old post from when I was first learning programming. Also, the second method is the better one anyway

Answer (score 3):

I would register events on mouseover and whenever the event happens trigger a function

```
$("#elm1, #elm2").on("mouseover", function () {
    // effect here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply add the handler to both elements like this :

```
$('#elm1, #elm2').hover(function(){
     // ... do stuff here ...
});
```

Should work . . .